# Design issue in class and a function

Tags: c++, oop, templates, c++11

I have a tree class Tree and I want to be able to build it in different ways. The build() function will be called in the constructor of Tree.

The result, in terms of space and data structures will be exactly the same, but the way of building the tree will vary (where every element will be places, in which node/leaf). The number of nodes and leaves is known before hand.

However, the build(), has a specific prototype. I would like the user, to just look at an `interface` and know what he has to implement.

So, I was thinking of going with a `template`. After writing the code, I noticed that the user of the Tree doesn't have any **interface** to see the prototype of the build(). Of course, I can write it in the documentation or let him/her face the compilation error, but that's not a good idea, IMHO.

In this case, the user would do:

```
Tree<SplitClass> tree; // ideal, if I could somehow notify him for the prototype
```

So, I thought about `abstract` classes and `(pure) virtual methods`. Again, this worked, but now the user has to do something like this:

```
Base* a = new SplitClass;
Tree(a);
```

Here, what I don't like, is that the user has to do use `new` and the users might not be so good in programming. Moreover, the user can not do it at once, like the `template` case.

Finally, I tried with a `function pointer`, which again will work, but no idea for the interface.

And of course, there is the solution of declaring and defining the splitting functions in other file(s) and include them.

[EDIT]

The fact that just to define one (very important for the project) function, one should create a class, is a bad idea?

[EDIT.2]

The prototype of build() takes only a `std::vector` and some `size_t` variables. In that phase, I am only building the tree, so I do not have any working example of how it will be used later.

[EDIT.3]

Minimal working example, which uses a `template`. Also, the `virtual` keyword comes into play.

This will work, but the user, might implement a class of his own, that will not inherit from `Base` and pass it the class `Calc`. I do not want him to be able to do that.

`Calc` is the class `Tree` I have in the actual project and `A` and `B` the splitting classes.

```
#include <iostream>

template<class Operation>
class Calc {
public:
    Calc(int arg) :
        a(arg) {
        Operation o(a, 10);
        o.add(a);
    }

    void print() {
        std::cout << a << "\n";
    }

private:
    int a;
};

class Base {
protected:
    virtual void add(int& a) = 0;
};

class A: public Base {
public:
    A(int& a, int c) {
        a = a + c;
    }

    virtual void add(int& a) {
        a += 100;
    }
};

class B: public Base {
public:
    B(int& a, int c) {
        a = a - c;
    }

    virtual void add(int& a) {
        a += 100000;
    }

};

int main() {

    Calc<A> a(2);
    a.print();

    Calc<B> b(2);
    b.print();

    return 0;
}
```

[EDIT.4]

Since, there is no alternative proposed, which is the one I should follow from the ones I already have? The best option, in terms of `OOP` "rules".

My target is not only making the design decision, but also to get educated, in an aspect of which is the way to go in the `OOP` world.

[EDIT.5]

And now, I feel that the two splitting classes, should take different number of arguments (one more the second one!).

If you think, that this question is un-constructive or to broad, let me know and I will delete it.

Comment: So the user implements `SplitClass` or some other class/function and then passes it to the tree's constructor in order to build the tree? Could you show us some more examples and how this class/function looks like and is used?

Comment: @dyp exactly! I haven't any other minimal example in mind. I will edit what the prototype looks like. I am in the phase which I build the tree, so only the creation comes into play for now. I want a simple way to construct the tree (like the one with the `template`), but somehow, I want the build() to be forced to have a specific prototype (like the `virtual` keyword allows us to do to) and the user to be able to notify the constructor which build() should it use. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: You're probably looking for a *concept*, which will hopefully be specified in this year as a ISO Technical Specification (but they will not be part of the C++14 Standard itself).

Comment: Which means, that I must go with the options described in my question. Do you think @dyp that I should delete the question or it be good for archive? Maybe, you write a more analytical answer based on your comment, so that the community knows that this question is answered.

Comment: There are probably alternatives, but it might help if you construct a minimal compilable example. The information is a bit scattered in the question. I wouldn't delete a question that is a duplicate or doesn't have a good solution yet (which might even not apply to your question), those can still be found via google and can link to other questions/answers.

Comment: @dyp I did. You probably meant questions that are not a duplicate? I will delete this comment in some minutes.

Comment: No! Duplicate questions should **not** be deleted, since they often use other tags and/or other formulations than older ("original") questions. StackOverflow has a dedicated system to mark duplicate questions. When there are multiple duplicates to a question, the question can be found more easily due to different tags/formulations/..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Since, there is no alternative proposed, which is the one I should follow from the ones I already have? The best option, in terms of OOP "rules".

C++ is a multi-paradigm programming language, so you don't need to use class hierarchies and virtual functions all the time (fortunately). Use OO if your problem is hierarchical, or if it can be described well in a hierarchical form.

To specialize algorithms in C++, you typically use function objects. A function object is a function pointer or class objects with an overloaded `operator()`:

```
#include <iostream>

class Calc {
public:
    template<class Op>
    Calc(int arg, Op op)
        : a(arg) {
        op(a);
    }

    void print() {
        std::cout << a << "\n";
    }

private:
    int a;
};
```

If the function object is only used in the constructor, you don't need to store it, hence you don't need to know its type in the class `Calc`. We then can "templatize" only the constructor instead of the whole class.

This constructor however is unrestricted in its second parameter: It can take anything but will fail to compile if `op(a)` is invalid. To restrict the types for `Op`, *concepts* are currently being specified. Hopefully, they'll be published in this year (2014) as an ISO Technical Specification.

Until we get them, we can use ugly SFINAE techniques and `static_assert`s to make the error messages better.

---

You *can* use inheritance here to express a concept, though. By using templates, you could still avoid virtual function calls. For example:

```
class MyInterface {
protected:
    virtual void add(int& a) = 0;
};

class A final
    : public MyInterface
{
public:
    A(int& a, int c) {
        a = a + c;
    }

    virtual void add(int& a) final override {
        a += 100;
    }
};
```

By making `A` final, or just `add`, the compiler can (could) infer that this is the final overrider of the virtual function, and avoid the dispatch.

```
class Calc {
public:
    template<class Op>
    Calc(int arg, Op op)
        : a(arg) {
        static_assert( std::is_base_of<MyInterface, Op>(),
                       "Op must implement MyInterface" );
        op(a);
    }

    void print() {
        std::cout << a << "\n";
    }

private:
    int a;
};
```

We can easily check if a class is derived from some other class, this can serve as a simplified version of a concept-check.

However, this constructor is still greedy: It produces an overload ranked as an Exact Match for all types in the second parameter. You'd have to use a SFINAE-technique to make it less greedy if that becomes a problem.

Comment: A last thing. It seems that the one class will need one more argument. So, I was thinking about Variable Argument List or making both accept the same number of arguments and just comment the extra argument in the one class (in the function of the class). I am feeling that the arg. list will produce some overhead. Do you think that this a bad idea?

Comment: @G.Samaras If you mean the `va_args` etc. feature, you shouldn't use that if you can avoid it. It has *lots* of problems. You should pass all arguments from the ctor to `Op` that could potentially be used in `Op`. If you choose the Abstract Base Class approach, this of course means that all derived classes will get all of the arguments. If one of those derived classes doesn't need all arguments, it can just ignore them - e.g. don't give the parameter a name in the overrider. If you don't use the ABC approach, you could use variadic templates to accept additional arguments.